# How to Filter through a column and select criteria for a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date column, description column, and symbol column. I am trying to generate a list that given a specific symbol, the formula would gather all of the data under the description column for a specific date. For example, I would like to generate a list of the description column that contains the symbol "CAT" for the date "2021-08-21" . The result I am aiming to achieve is in the List column.

[image]

The formula I tried using is

```
=IF(DATE(2021,8,21),IF(B2:B9=LEFT(C2,33),B2,""))
```

Comment: Thank you for showing what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one has Office 365 then use FILTER:

```
=FILTER(B:B,(C:C="CAT")*(A:A=DATE(2021,8,21)),"")
```

[image]

---

If not then Put this in the first cell and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($C$2:$C$9)/(($C$2:$C$9="CAT")*($A$2:$A$9=DATE(2021,8,21))),ROW($ZZ1))),"")
```

[image]